# Unable to create "virtual" fields with RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I want to add a button to my rails_admin model edit pane that does what I want (automatically post something to Facebook).  I added:

```
field :post_to_facebook do
  formatted_value do
     bindings[:view].post_event_to_facebook bindings[:object]
  end
end
```

And I had this helper to actually create the button:

```
module EventsHelper
  def post_event_to_facebook object
    link_to "Post to facebook!" , "/post/to/facebook"
  end
end
```

In `<site.com>/rails_admin/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-68f5258e9af2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml`,

it errors out:

```
undefined method `post_to_facebook' for #<Event:0x007ff23704b768>
```

My buddy who is also doing an RA-backed site, did exactly this and had success - am I not updating RailsAdmin properly?  What's happening?

Edit: I am on rails 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@template.link_to "Post to facebook!" , "/post/to/facebook"
```

Helpers don't have the views mixed-in.

Comment: This didn't work for me either - I think RA is complaining about :post_to_facebook, not /post/to/facebook.